# eigenvalues of permutation matrices proving

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutations

How to prove or disprove the "absolute value" of eigenvalues (including imaginary-number eigenvalues) of permutation matrices are 1, using only the knowledge of elementary linear algebra?

Comment: So what are the eigenvalues of
$$\pmatrix{0&1&0\cr0&0&1\cr1&0&0}?$$

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Sorry. edited.

Answer (score 3):

Each permutation matrix satisfies $A^m=I$ for some $m$.

What does that tell you about is eigenvalues?

Comment: $λ^m=1$, if $A^m=I$